# concurrent view limit being exceeded

Tags: jsf, icefaces

Have been looking around to investigate the cause of the following exception messages. These messages are getting printed in the logs numerous times during peak load of the application server. I have come across some articles which state that the default concurrent view limit being 50 or so. Also came across some write up about potential view leak. I can track the requests being made from the browser to see what kind of jsf (ajax) requests may be possibly causing these view leaks.

> <[ServletContext@898084041[app:nwf-portal module:nwf-portal.war path:null spec-version:3.0]] Root cause of ServletException. java.lang.RuntimeException: Concurrent view limit exceeded. at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.MultiViewServer.createView(MultiViewServer.java:124) at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.MultiViewServer.service(MultiViewServer.java:100) at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.ServerProxy.service(ServerProxy.java:43)

However no clue yet about how to go about stopping these messages from showing up. Could these messages indicate a heap /memory issue ?

#### The question is:

Is there an authentic write-up or information about how to address this issue and what should be the approach to diagnose and stop these exceptions from showing ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the error alway occuring in an icefaces class? If so, why did you not tag the Q as such?

Comment: And what about increasing the concurrentviews? Since it only occurs on peaks I doubt it is a leak

Comment: Yes .The error always from icefaces class. Let me tag it that way.

Comment: I dont know the memory implications of increasing the concurrent view limit.The ajax requests from the clients browser keep coming for hours ,since they probably keep the browsers open.With this they keep on adding conversations/views to their session so even if I set it to 100, I doubt the requests will cross that limit in just matter of time.

Comment: Check if your memory usage now and see how far you can stretch it... That is called tuning

Comment: Did you **check** if that happens? (keep adding and adding views/conversations)? Just ajax calls should not do that

Comment: Yes ajax calls do do that.I brought down the concurrent view limit to 20 for now. So only 20 requests or new conversations for the server to handle (and allocate memory) before the error shows up.Also added code to stop certain ajax requests from being made continuously, after the first occurrence of this exception. Hope this will suffice.